# Probability of Collisions in Hash Table

Tags: math, hash, probability

When inserting n items into a hash table of size m, assuming that the destination of each item is independently uniformly random, what is the probability that no collision occurs?

---

My working thus far:
We have n items and m locations.
Each item has a 1/m chance of being in any particular location.
There are nC2 possible pairs of items.
The probability of there being no collisions is the probability that for every location, every pair of items does not hash to that location.

For any given location, for any given pair, the probability that the two items do not hash to that location is (m-1)/m.

Then, for any given location, the probability that the above is true for ALL pairs is ((m-1)/m)^(nC2).

Then, the probability that this is true for every location is
[((m-1)/m)^(nC2)]^(m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a few mistakes in that reasoning. The main one is that you assume that the probabilities for pairs not hashing together are independent, so you can multiply them together. You have not shown that is the case, and in fact it is not the case. Consider three elements a, b, and c. If you know that both a and b do not collide with c, then they are limited to m-1 places rather than the initial m places, and they are more likely to collide with each other than if you just ignore c.

Here is a straightforward way to find your desired probability. Looking at the total possibilities ignoring collisions, each of the n items has m places to go. Those placements are independent, so the total possibilities are m^n (or m**n in Python) if we take order into account.

If we know there are no collisions, those n items are a way of choosing out of the m locations without replacement. So if we take order into account, that makes mPn possibilities -- the ways to choose n items out of m choices without replacement and with order (permutations). Therefore your desired probability is

> mPn / m^n  = (m!) / ((m-n)! * m^n) = m/m * (m-1)/m * (m-2)/m * ... * (m-n+1)/m

There are n factors in that last expression. (This would be so much better in MathJax!) You can choose which of those three equivalent expressions is best for your purpose.

There are other ways to come up with those expressions, of course. That last one can be thought of as the probability of no collision placing 1 item in m slots times the conditional probability of placing a second item given no prior collision times the conditional probability of placing a third item given no prior collision times ....

Those expressions are fairly easy to test. Just choose specific, small values of m and n, generate all possible choices of n items out of those m, and find the empirical probability of no collisions. This should agree with the formula(s) above. I'll leave the choice of programming language and the coding to you. After all, this is a programming site. I just did this in Python, for multiple choices of n and m, and it works out.